# Does time have a changing speed?

Tags: philosophy-of-science, metaphysics, time, mysticism

Based on my own personal experiences and responses from other people I have questioned time is more than numbers.

Correct me if I’m wrong, but it seems to me that it is a fact that pleasure speeds up time and pain slows it down. Here are some common examples that express what I’m trying to explain: “like watching your paint dry” or “watching your grass grow” and of course “waiting for your water to boil.” These things don’t just seem to take longer, they actually take longer. Because time is relative. Right?

I don’t care what my watch says or how many times the cesium 6 atom resonates. I’ve experienced and endured eternal living heavens and hells in nothing more but moments. If you’ve ever been in a jail cell, been a victim of torture, had to sleep outside in the freezing cold, or been in any kind of pain or discomfort for prolonged periods of time you know what I mean when I say “those moments seem to last forever”. Seconds? Days? Years? Not when your in pain.

On the other end of the spectrum I’ve been places most scientists and philosophers couldn’t even fathom without exploring themselves. Infinite, tangible, very real inner-outer spaces. I’ve read multiple times that no person could ever comprehend or grasp infinity, but this isn’t true. I’ve lived, explored, and endured many different altered states of consciousness most of them from alkaloids extracted from plants that grow here on earth. The same place with the same perfect initial conditions that created us human beings.

It would be ignorant to label me crazy or not take me seriously because I use these “god given” keys to unlock doors to completely different dimensions. Some of these substances actually change the world around you as if the whole world was playing out like some movie. That’s all I’m going to say for now if someone could please share more info on this matter I would appreciate it.

Critiques, comments, links, advice, and questions are welcome. Thanks,
-George

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing the scientific definition of time (what a clock measures) with your intuitive feeling of how things change. This has nothing to do with  time being relative according to relativity theory.

Comment: "When you sit with a nice girl for two hours you think it's only a minute, but when you sit on a hot stove for a minute you think it's two hours. That's relativity." -A. Einstein

Answer (score 0):

That's not really a question, is it? I mean time in terms of physics is what the clock reads. So literally just the perception of (periodically repeating) change in your environment. And if you looked at a clock while traveling in the opposite direction at the speed of light then time would stand still as the information of the clock moving isn't reaching up to you. So yes time is relative.
And there are thought experiments like the [twin paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twin_paradox). About how time is moving differently.
Though in terms of physics your mental state isn't as important as your velocity.

So that comparison doesn't hold. So in that regard it's probably more about the perception of change that makes time fly or freeze. Like if everything around you rapidly moves you're feeling that time flies because hours have passed before you've grasped even a fraction of it. While absolute stand still or something that you want to stop but can't, makes it feel as if time is creeping at snails pace.

Answer (score 0):

It would  be more correct to say, the speed of time defines what space is. Space is the set of relations, defining the fastest possible signals, between points, or assemblies of values of fundamental constants, that we call particles.

Subjective timespeed certainly varies subjectively. Young people typically experience time moving much more slowly; a single years difference in age feels like a gulf, but as we age a year viewed as a percentage of lifespan, recedes. As we grow familar with experiences, we automate responses, to use fewer resources, and focus energy on novelty. As we age, we risk writing off more of our experiences as, not deserving our full attention, and it flying by.

It's interesting to compare boredom, and meditation. I think we can understand boredom as being more intensely painful for the young, because they are feeling driven to test themselves, to develop their faculties and skills. But when we have done so, it is skillful to develop beyond boredom, so we can sit with problems for longer and more deeply, without rushing to conclusions; and curb our compuliveness and immediate reactiveness.

Kahneman in 'Thinking Fast and Slow' prrovides a neurological basis for this. Our intuitive responses are tuned to be 'good enough', and our slow analytical resource-intensive responses are typically triggered when those automatised standard heuristics fail in prediction. Our brain's 'clock speed' ramps up, spending more mental energy and subjective time processing each input.

The research on DMT is very interesting. It's thought to be endogenous, and associated with being born, and near-death experiences. The theory goes that it opens the brain in a radical way bith to inputs from the moment, and to 'wild' free-association with any memories or inferences. While being born, there is no subjective memory-bank to draw on, but there is no more critical time to going on to develop. And DMT is implicated in 'your life flashing before your eyes' near death experiences, as literally a rapid scan using all your brain's resources for anything relevant or useful. In medical trials patients describe epic, life-changing elaborate visions, as happening in as little as five minutes of apparent unconsciousness.

Biologically, it was thought experiencing time passing would be some kind of higher-level emergent function. But it has turned out every cell has a sense of day and night, these synch up towards indicating time passing. When people go under medical anaesthesia or go into a coma, very often the sense of time passing is lost, in a way it isn't during sleep or other kinds of unconsciousness.

We have an idea that time passing is a 'universal clock', so that we can relate events systematically between everywhere. But we can't, because all the 'points' are just moments when the matter-waves of uncertainty are interupted by taking a measurement. A lot of information is fundamentally 'folded-in' to quantum encertainties, 'inside' the uncertainty-principle, in a way that involves time certainty disturbing position certainty and vice versa. The systematic relation of time is limited to classical Relativistic picture. Using Noether's Theorem, we can understand space-time not as an inert background specifying relations between 'pixels', but as sets of locality relations defined by symmetries under transformation, and that what we call dimensions are that and are *directly equivalent* to conservation laws. The degree of uncertainty of a quantum object relates to how many states it can be in, and we  an relate that to conservation of information  - the 2nd law of thermodynamics  tells us that the forward direction in time always involves maintaining or increasing the possible sub-states. Spacially, the Feynman diagrams of interactions can be rotated and be equivalent. But the Arrow of Time emerges because it *is* equivalent to a symmetry property, transformation into the same or more sub-states of quantum objects

(Chiribella's Purification Principle tells us this conservation of information/entropy increase relates to the spreading out but not concentrating of correlations, with quantum behaviour as defined by states small enough the spreading out rule doesn't dominate, and new pure states can emerge from signal-seperated and therefore quantum objects).